# Pass more than one argument to functions

Tags: php

I've created the following function that simply echos 'active' if a chosen day string is passed to it:

```
function active_day($theday) {
    if (date('D') == $theday) {
        echo 'active';
    }
}
```

The function works fine if I pass in one argument e.g.

```
active_day( 'Sun' );
```

However, I'd like to pass in two arguments, e.g.

```
active_day( 'Sun', 'Mon' );
```

This works fine for Sunday, but it ignores Monday for some reason.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Must read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the function declaration itself.

```
function active_day($theday,$anotherday)
```

As you have defined the function to take a single argument, it takes only a single argument.

### Other Alternatives

In your case you can pass your params as an array to your function.

```
function active_day($newarr) {

  //  if (date('D') == $theday) {
  //      echo 'active';
  //  }

  echo $newarr[0];//Sun
  echo $newarr[1];//Mon
}

$arr= array('Sun','Mon');
active_day($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your function to only accept one argument - and then checking that one argument.  If you intend to pass more than one argument, then declare it as such:

```
function active_day($theday, $secondday);
```

Then you can call it with two days:

```
active_day( 'Sun', 'Mon' );
```

If you don't know in advance how many arguments you are going to pass, you can use `func_get_args` function and change your function accordingly:

```
function active_day() {
    $days = func_get_args();
    foreach($days as $day) {
        echo "$day - ";
        if (date('D') == $day) {
            echo 'active';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Youre looking for PHP func_get_args:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

**Will output:**

Number of arguments: 3
Second argument is: 2
Argument 0 is: 1
Argument 1 is: 2
Argument 2 is: 3

Comment: -1 for a blind copy_paste of the func_get_args documentation

Comment: you're right, but perfect explanation for using function args

Comment: No, not a perfect explanation.  A perfect explanation would be if you actually changed the sample code to match the question.